# Laravel Input validation Between is not validate correctly

Tags: php, validation, laravel

currently i'm facing some issue in laravel input validation where the validation rules for between seems like doesnt apply correctly. Below is my HTML code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <div class="margin-bottom-10">
                    <label>Thread Title :</label>
                    <input name="thread_title" maxlength="100" required>
                </div>                  
                <div class="margin-bottom-10">
                    <label>Price :</label>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" required title="Please enter price with x.xx format." name="thread_item_price" />
                </div>
```

What i'm trying to do is to validate the given price must be between 0 and 9999.99. I inspect element and remove the min="0" and try to submit with negative value says -1000, the system seems to accept the input. Below is my validator rules

```
$validator = Validator::make($request::all(),
            [
                'thread_title' => 'required|max:100',
                'thread_item_price' => 'between:0,9999.99'
            ],
            [
                'thread_title.required' => 'Please fill in thread title.',
                'thread_title.max' => 'Thread title has exceeded 100 characters.',
                'thread_item_price.required' => 'Price cannot be empty.',
                'thread_item_price.between' => 'Price must be equals to 0 or 9999.99.',
            ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        };
```

Am i doing something wrong and make the validation failed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to let Laravel know that it's a numeric value. This should work for you.

```
'thread_item_price' => 'numeric|between:0,9999.99'
```

Comment: Beware: Based on the code of 'between': https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L336 You aren't validating actual number of decimal positions, only that the number is between two real values: The 0 and the 9999.9900000... If you try to validate 9999.981 it will be accepted (and probably rounded to 9999.98 after), but if you try with 9999.991 it will fail.

Answer (score 4):

Between rule accept only integers for numerics. You should use [digits_between](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-digits-between) rule for float numbers.

Edit: 
I don't know why Laravel accept it, validation rule digits_between use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function. You can try regex rule:

```
['thread_item_price' => 'regex:/^\d{0,4}\.\d{2}$/'];
```

Comment: There is no need to run a regex. `digits_between` checks the number of digits, not the numeric value of the input. `between` works, but you need to let Laravel know that it's a numeric value as shown in my answer.